# How to select multiple nodes in Kendo TreeView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to select multiple nodes in Kendo TreeView but it is not working.

Can't we select multiple nodes in Kendo Treeview without using Checkbox?

Comment: Not by default, I'm afraid. You will have to make it by your own, but it is possible I think. Describe what do you mean by *select* a node. Just clicking over it ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yeah, just by clicking over it.

Comment: I think you can use events preventDefault() to prevent normal selection, could you refer this: https://www.telerik.com/forums/example-treeview-with-multiple-node-selections#ElSIEBRHNEyahZjd1Ta_Mw